# wamp / composer/ laravel5 : localhost:8000 just stopped working for no reason

Tags: php, laravel, server, wamp, composer-php

I installed Wamp, then composer, then Laravel 5, I opened the page localhost:8000 and Laravel confirmation appeared.

I didn't don anything else, 4 days later, I tried localhost:8000 however now I get "This web page is not available" message rather than laravel5 logo..

Anyone has any idea what could I do?

Thanks

Comment: Try to check at `services.msc`, are all the services you need are up and running(eg mysql..). Also check the startup type. And disable the firewall for a while to check if it blocked your port.

Answer (score 3):

When you you run a laravel application you must do the following:

1. start the wamp server.
2. after that write in terminal `php artisan serve`
3. then go to the browser and search for `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Thanks @Dawlatzai, I started wamp server (after resolving skype conflict), however when I type `php artisan serve` on command prompt (running windows 10) I get the message `Could not open input file: artisan`, have you any idea why?

Comment: You can write on command prompt (composer install) it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Dawlatzai, another way I found out would would be to open the command prompt, then type cd + the project folder address eg. `cd c:\myfolder\myproject` and then enter, then type php artisan serve as you said :) it's all working now thanks to you